# date: bad conversion error on HP-UX but not on Linux

Tags: date, touch

On Linux:

```
$ touch 1 12
```

No problem,create `1` and `12`.

On SysV or HP-UX 11.31:

```
$ touch 1 12
date: bad conversion
```

I have tried with `LANG=C`, same error.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this hp man page for touch: http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02273390

... the command expects the following form for touch:
`touch time_str file_name`

That form is recognized `when neither the -r option, the -t
option, nor the -- option delimiter is specified, and the first operand consists of all decimal digits.`

Answer (score 3):

The [original `touch` command](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/man/man1/touch.1) only supported setting the file's modification time to the current time.

Historical System V systems introduced the ability to specify a time as the first argument, with the syntax `[YY]MMDDhhmm` (optional year, month, day, hours, minutes). At that time, the convention to use a dash and a letter followed by a value for optional arguments (like `-t …`) was not fully established. This created an incompatibility with earlier versions, with commands like yours — `touch 1 12` originally meant setting the timestamp on two files called `1` and `12`, but from that point SysV unices started interpreting the `1` (or any first argument consisting entirely of digits) as a timestamp.

Some modern unices, including HP-UX, have chosen to maintain compatibility with these SysV versions. Others, including *BSD and recent GNU versions, have never had or have dropped support for this syntax.

[Earlier versions of POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/touch.html) specified both `touch TIME FILE…` and `touch [-t TIME] FILE…`, but since [POSIX-2001](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/touch.html), only the syntax with the `-t` option is supported.

To make your script portable, if it's possible for the first argument of `touch` to be a file whose name consists entirely of digits, or of digits and a dot, either put `--` before the file (that's what POSIX recommends, so hopefully it works everywhere) or put `./` at the beginning of the file name:

```
touch -- 1 12
```

or

```
case "$file" in
  /*) :;;
  *) file="./$file";;
esac
touch "$file"
```